# Core 2.0 Restsharp build warnings with System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-2.0

This is the warning I get on Publish, basically any dotnet command... I'm unsure how to resolve. My dependancies are riddled with yellow warning symbols now (after moving to 2.0).  When drilling down it usually ends up as a dependancy on `Newtonsoft.Json` which in turn references `System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters`.

Anyone else have this, what resolves it?

### ERROR

> warning NU1603: RestSharp.NetCore 105.2.3 depends on
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters (>= 4.0.0-rc4-24217-03) but
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters 4.0.0-rc4-24217-03 was not
>   found. An approximate best match of
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters 4.3.0-preview1-24530-04 was
>   resolved.

Comment: Restsharp doesn't work on .net core yet. It's been basically abandon ware since 2015, and only picked up again in the lat month or so. There's a link to the epic here for it: https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/992 (Restsharp may not be the tool for the job; look around, refit or restease might be what you're looking for).

Comment: (...and I know, that's a strange thing to say given there's literally a Restsharp.NetCore, but its never worked on the 2.x core line afaik)

Answer (score 0):

The **RestSharp.NetCore** project doesn't belong to the official team of [the RestSharp](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp) package. Refer to [this discuss](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/992) under official repository for details about the RestSharp package's support of the .NET Standard 2.0.

Now you can use the latest stable version of [the RestSharp package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RestSharp/106.1.0) which supports .NET Core 2.0